# Navigation menu does not have blur effect for background

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to add the background-filter blur effect to my nav bar and nav menu for the mobile web view but I have a problem. The problem is that I can add the blur effect to the nav bar but not the nav menu. I have tried adding the CSS code for both the nav bar and nav menu but only the nav bar would have the blur effect while the nav menu do not. I only managed to get either one to have the blur at any time but I want both of them to have the effect.

[Image of my nav bar having the blur filter while the nav menu do not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIGf3.png)

The react.js code for nav bar and nav menu

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import logo from "../Win7.svg";
import { Link, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { IconContext } from "react-icons/lib";
import { FaBars, FaTimes } from "react-icons/fa";
import "./Nav.css";

export default function Header() {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);
  const closeMobileMenu = () => setClick(false);

  return (
    <>
      <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: "#fff" }}>
        <nav className="nav-bar">
          <div className="navbar-container container">
            <Link to="/" className="navbar-logo">
              <p className="logo" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                <img src={logo} alt="React logo" height={40} />
              </p>
            </Link>
            <div className="menu-icon" onClick={handleClick}>
              {click ? <FaTimes /> : <FaBars />}
            </div>
            <ul className={click ? "nav-menu active" : "nav-menu"}>
              <li className="links">
                <NavLink
                  to="/claims"
                  className={({ isActive }) =>
                    "link" + (isActive ? " activated" : "")
                  }
                  onClick={closeMobileMenu}
                >
                  Claims
                </NavLink>
              </li>
              <li className="links">
                <NavLink
                  to="/PNav"
                  className={({ isActive }) =>
                    "link" + (isActive ? " activated" : "")
                  }
                  onClick={closeMobileMenu}
                >
                  PFile
                </NavLink>
              </li>
              <li className="links">
                <NavLink
                  to="/about"
                  className={({ isActive }) =>
                    "link" + (isActive ? " activated" : "")
                  }
                  onClick={closeMobileMenu}
                >
                  About Us
                </NavLink>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </IconContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}
```

CSS for the nav bar and menu

````css
.nav-bar {
    width: auto;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0rem 1rem;
    background-color: rgba(0, 158, 199, 0.6);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 25px 0 rgba(0, 158, 199, 0.6);
    z-index: 88;
    backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
  }

  .nav-bar ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .link {
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0d47a1;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  .link:hover {
    scale: 1.15;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  
  .link:active {
    scale: 0.9;
    background-color: green;
    color: blue;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  
  .logo {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    display:flex;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .logo:hover {
    scale: 1.15;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  
  .logo:active {
    scale: 0.9;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }

  .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }

  .activated {
    color: blueviolet;
  }

  .navbar-container, .container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .NavbarItems {
      position: relative;
    }
  
   .nav-menu {
      flex-direction: column;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 63px;
      left: -145%;
      align-items: center;
      transition: all 0.6s ease;
      height: 175%;
      overflow: hidden;
     }
  
    .nav-menu.active {
      background-color: rgba(0, 158, 199, 0.6);
      left: 0;
      z-index: 88;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 0;
      height: 175%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .links, .link {
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      padding-left: 0;
      padding-top: 2.5px;
      margin-left: 5px;
    }

    .link:hover {
      transform: scale(1.05);
      background-color: transparent;
    }
  
    .logo {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
  
    .menu-icon {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: -5px;
      right: 0;
      transform: translate(-100%, 60%);
      font-size: 1.8rem;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }```
````

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing might be related to the backdrop-filter not being applied to child elements within the .nav-bar. The backdrop-filter property affects the element's backdrop and its children.

To ensure that the blur effect is applied to both the navbar and the menu, you can set the backdrop-filter property on both the .nav-bar and the .nav-menu elements. Additionally, you should make sure that the parent element of the .nav-menu also has the backdrop-filter property set.

Here's an updated version of your CSS with modifications:

```
.nav-bar {
  width: auto;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0rem 1rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 158, 199, 0.6);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 25px 0 rgba(0, 158, 199, 0.6);
  z-index: 88;
  backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
}

.nav-menu-container {
  backdrop-filter: blur(8px); /* Apply blur to the parent container of .nav-menu */
}

.nav-bar ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

/* ... rest of your CSS */

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  /* ... other styles */

  .nav-menu-container {
    backdrop-filter: blur(8px); /* Apply blur to the parent container of .nav-menu */
  }

  .nav-menu {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 63px;
    left: -145%;
    align-items: center;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
    height: 175%;
    overflow: hidden;
    backdrop-filter: blur(8px); /* Apply blur to .nav-menu */
  }

  /* ... other styles */
}
```

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { FaBars, FaTimes } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { IconContext } from 'react-icons/lib';
import './YourComponent.css'; // Replace with the actual CSS file name

const Navbar = () => {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);
  const closeMobileMenu = () => setClick(false);

  return (
    <>
      <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: '#fff' }}>
        <nav className="nav-bar">
          <div className="navbar-container container">
            <Link to="/" className="navbar-logo">
              <p className="logo" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                Your Logo
              </p>
            </Link>
            <div className="menu-icon" onClick={handleClick}>
              {click ? <FaTimes /> : <FaBars />}
            </div>
            <div className="nav-menu-container"> {/* Add nav-menu-container here */}
              <ul className={click ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
                <li className="links">
                  <NavLink
                    to="/claims"
                    className={({ isActive }) =>
                      'link' + (isActive ? ' activated' : '')
                    }
                    onClick={closeMobileMenu}
                  >
                    Claims
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className="links">
                  <NavLink
                    to="/PNav"
                    className={({ isActive }) =>
                      'link' + (isActive ? ' activated' : '')
                    }
                    onClick={closeMobileMenu}
                  >
                    PFile
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className="links">
                  <NavLink
                    to="/about"
                    className={({ isActive }) =>
                      'link' + (isActive ? ' activated' : '')
                    }
                    onClick={closeMobileMenu}
                  >
                    About Us
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </IconContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

In this modification, I added a new class .nav-menu-container to the parent container of the .nav-menu and applied the backdrop-filter: blur(8px) property to both the .nav-menu-container and the .nav-menu. Ensure that you add the nav-menu-container class to the appropriate parent element in your JSX/React code.

Comment: where do I add the nav-menu-container to in the react.js code?

Comment: I updated the code

Comment: I noticed that adding that div will mess with the layout of the nav menu so now I cannot see the nav menu in the mobile view when I click the hamburger menu. Ok the thing is if I add blur to the .nav-bar it will show on the bar but not on the .nav-menu but if I remove the blur from .nav-bar, the blur for .nav-menu is there but not for the .nav-bar.

Comment: I noticed that if I remove the backdrop-filter from. .nav-bar and keep the one in .nav-menu, the menu will have the blur effect. If I add the backdrop-filter onto the .nav-bar, then only the nav bar gets the blur.

Comment: I still can only get either the nav bar or nav menu to have blur effect and not both of them @Shatha